# Node.js crashing when connecting to AWS S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, debian, digital-ocean, knox-amazon-s3-client

After migrating my application from IntoVPS to Digital Ocean, my application crashes when it tries to upload photos to AWS S3.

The differences between the servers are: IntoVPS was running Ubuntu 10.10, and Digital Ocean is running Debian; IntoVPS had node 0.8.x, and Digital Ocean has 0.10.26.

There are no firewalls on the new server that could be causing this issue (I've checked).

The crash errors are:

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
  at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
  at Pipe.onread (net.js:558:19)

Error: spawn ENOENT
  at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
  at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:779:34)

Error: write EPIPE
  at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
  at Object.afterWrite (net.js:720:19)
```

Some of these might be related to forever trying to restart the process (I figured that's what spawn might mean). The one I'd focus on is the ECONNRESET one.

So, I'm running my process using forever, and I'm using the knox module to connect to S3.

After googling I found: https://github.com/LearnBoost/knox/issues/198

I tried adding `res.resume()` to the callback of `putFile` like it says in the, but nothing changes; I still get the ECONNRESET error.

*I've spent an entire day (yesterday) trying to fix this issue, and I can't continue having my production application be broken, so I decided to try switching to an older version of Node in order to temporarily (but quickly) fix this issue. So, I installed the n module to try and get 0.8.26 as the node version installed. Unfortunately, n didn't work, and here's the issue I created on that: https://github.com/visionmedia/n/issues/170*

**EDIT:**

After exiting my ssh session and opening a new one, n is working. However, switching to 0.8.26 version of node causes another errors:

```
/apps/Foobar/node_modules/dnode/node_modules/weak/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:83
        throw e
              ^
Error: Module version mismatch, refusing to load.
  at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:485:11)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
  at require (module.js:378:17)
  at bindings (/apps/Foobar/node_modules/dnode/node_modules/weak/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:76:44)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/apps/Foobar/node_modules/dnode/node_modules/weak/lib/weak.js:1:97)
  at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
  at require (module.js:378:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/apps/Foobar/node_modules/dnode/index.js:5:12)
  at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
  at require (module.js:378:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/apps/Foobar/controllers/sock.js:2:13)
  at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
  at require (module.js:378:17)
  at global.Controller (/apps/Foobar/globals.js:2:9)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/apps/Foobar/controllers/generosity.js:209:12)
  at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
  at require (module.js:378:17)
  at global.Controller (/apps/Foobar/globals.js:2:9)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/apps/Foobar/app.js:282:1)
  at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
  at process.startup.processNextTick.process._tickCallback (node.js:245:9)
```

As you can see I'm having the darnedest time trying to fix this issue with S3, and I'm to the point of crying (metaphorically). I can't keep wasting time on this issue, but I can't seem to solve it. It's almost like Node itself is broken.

Can anyone provide any insight on what's going on? Any help with this is appreciated.

Why isn't knox working anymore?

**EDIT**

Here's more details.

Code that errors:

```
// S3
var endpoint = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/"+global.config.aws.s3.bucket+"/";
var knox = require('knox');
var s3 = knox.createClient(global.config.aws.s3);
var photosPrefix = 'photos/';


var model = module.exports;

model.emitter = new events.EventEmitter;


// ::Photos
model.createPhoto = function(info, cb){
    if (!info.file || path.resolve(info.file) === path.resolve(global.__tempdir))
        return cb(new Error('missing info.file'));

    var db = info.db;
    var photoId;

    if (typeof info.public === 'undefined')
        info.public = false;

    // Move file to a specific location
    var basename = path.basename(info.file);
    var destination = photosPrefix+basename+'/original';

    yarn
    (function(){
        // Upload photo to AWS
        s3.putFile(
            info.file, 
            destination, 
            {
                'Content-Type': 'image/png'
            },
            this());
    })
    (function(err, res){
        if (err) return this.error(new Error(err));

        // Remove temporary file
        fs.unlink(info.file, this());
    })
    (function(err){
        if (err) return this.error(new Error(err));

        // Retrieve photo stream from AWS
        s3.getFile(destination, this());
    })
    (function(err, res){
        if (err) return this.error(new Error(err));

        // Get the dimensions of the photo using the stream (res)
        gm(res).size(this());
    })
    (function(err, size){
        if (err) return this.error(new Error(err));

        // Insert record into photos table (include the dimensions, width and height)
        db.query("INSERT photos (resource, width, height, public) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", [basename, size.width, size.height, info.public], this());
    })
    (function(err, results){
        if (err) return this.error(new Error(err));

        photoId = results.insertId;

        cb(null, photoId);
    })
    .error(function(err){
        cb(err);
    });
}
```

All photos no matter what the size or format cause the same error.

Comment: Regarding your updated issue - maybe a "of course I did" question, but did you clear out node_modules and then reinstall after downgrading node? A guess is that breaking changes between 0.8.x and 0.10.x are impacting the modules you had. Also, I do not know if npm is smart enough to install the correct older versions based on "engines" (which may not always be useful anyway) of modules or if you will need to manually specify versions. I have not had occasion to do a downgrade myself. Maybe someone can confirm npm behavior in this case. The doc doesn't specify that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue wasn't with AWS and knox, but rather with gm and the fact that GraphicsMagick wasn't installed on my system.

For reference for others, if you're experiencing similar errors, remember that gm doesn't report that GraphicsMagick or ImageMagick are absent when they are absent. I reported this error on the gm module here: https://github.com/aheckmann/gm/issues/273